# AngularJS with ng-include src using controller function

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to use function inside the src of ng-include but the code below doesn't work. I already tried using single quotation mark inside the double quotation mark but still not working.

**TEMPLATE**

```
<div ng-include src="{{templateUrl('tables/requestTable.html')}}"></div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.templateUrl = (url) => {
    return 'https://example.com/url';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)'s `src` doesn't need curly braces. You can directly pass the function.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('test', function($scope) {
    $scope.templateUrl = function() {
      return 'url';
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="test">
  <div ng-include src="templateUrl()"></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="url">test template</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. my bad i forgot that you dont need to use curly braces on ng-